# Formula with integral operator adjoint

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory

I have to show that

$$(J + J*)f = (Jf)(b)1 = <f,1>\cdot 1$$

where $1$ evaluates to a constant 1 in $[a,b]$ and $J$ is the integration operator on $H = L^2(a,b)$.

I know that

$$J* = \int_a^b \overline{k(t,s)}f(s)ds$$

which makes this

$$\int_a^b k(t,s)f(s) dx + \int_a^b \overline{k(t,s)}f(s) dx = \int_a^b f(s) (k(t,s) \cdot \overline{k(s,t)})ds$$

but I don't really know how to go from there. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you clarify what the notation $(Jf)(b)1$ means?

Comment: @CheeHan $Jf$ is a function and $b$ is the parameter of that function.